# Google PAY API - LoyalityObject vs LoyalityClass

Tags: google-pay

I'm starting to look at the Google Pay API (.Net).
I'm not clear on the difference between the LoyalityObject and the LoyalityClass.
Which is used for which? Which is the Loyality Card?
thanks in advance

```
 public static LoyaltyClass generateLoyaltyClass(string issuerId, string classId)
```

vs

```
 public static LoyaltyObject generateLoyaltyObject(string issuerId, string classId, string objectId)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [here](https://developers.google.com/pay/passes/guides/overview/basics/classes-and-objects):

> The Google Pay API for Passes uses the concept of an Object to digitally represent a single user's physical loyalty cards, gift cards, offers, event tickets, and boarding passes for flights. The API uses the concept of a Class to allow management of data common across all users. To cover specific use cases, each vertical has its own respective Object and Class.

So the LoyalityObject is each users Loyalty Card, and the LoyaltyClass is to allow management of data common across all users.